# How to resize the length of the two ends of the arrow heads in TiKz / PGF?

Tags: arrows

Are you looking for alternatives and simpler than my MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw [draw, black,help lines, xstep=1cm, ystep=1cm] (0,0) grid  (7.5,16.5);
        \draw (0,0) [->,>=angle 45,line width=2pt] --(4.5,9);
        \draw[-{Straight Barb[angle=35:.3cm 1,length=9mm]},line width=1pt] (0,0) - - (1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[Reference to alternatives solutions](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf)

Comment: You can answer your own question, but there is a procedure to follow for this, read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Your second arrow, `\draw[-{Straight Barb[angle=35:.3cm 1,length=9mm]},line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (1,5);`, already uses `arrows.meta`, and even adjusts the length. So the answer to your question may be: load `arrows.meta` (which you are already doing) and then adjust the length key (which you are already doing). Therefore it is not clear what additional information you expect from an answer. (BTW, I personally would not want to mix `arrows` and `arrows,meta` but would rather use only `arrows.meta`.)

Comment: yes, @marmot. I had not noticed when I posted it.

Comment: OK, but what answer do you expect/hope for?

Comment: I think a solution that uses macros through pgf, and less TiKz commands.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question, you are searching for a way to draw your arrows without writing all the options every time.

In this case, you can create some TikZ styles and use them every time you need them.

Off-topic:

- don't put `draw` as an option of `draw`, it is useless
- if `xstep` is equal to `ystep` you can simply use `step`
- as marmot suggested, avoid using `arrows`, just use the `arrows.meta` (for example, see `mythickarrowmeta` style instead of `mythickarrow` in my MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    mygrid/.style={help lines, step=1cm},
    mythickarrow/.style={->,>=angle 45,line width=2pt},
    mythickarrowmeta/.style={-{Straight Barb[angle=45:.25cm 1,length=8pt]}
    ,line width=2pt},
    mythinarrow/.style={-{Straight Barb[angle=35:.3cm 1,length=9mm]},line width=1pt},
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw[mygrid] (0,0) grid (7.5,16.5);
        \draw[mythickarrow] (0,0) -- (4.5,9);
        \draw[mythickarrowmeta] (0,0) -- (5,9);
        \draw[mythinarrow] (0,0) -- (1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]